# Yet another Overfull \vbox

Tags: formatting, compiling, warnings

My document is a kind of long thesis that I will not copy paste here. When I compile it, everything goes fine, except for the following warning

```
Overfull \vbox (1.83182pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

My problem is I don't know where this comes from, since no line is specified (I'm using Texmaker with Miktex, and Texmaker says the Badbox is at line 1; however I suspect this is just Texmaker saying that, because there's nothing else specified in the log file and the title is just fine). And since I don't understand the origin of the problem, I don't know how to correct it.

Comment: If you look at the `log` file you should at least be able to see on which page this is occurring.

Comment: What document class are you using? Are you setting the page parameters with `geometry`? There are a lot of details that can help even without reporting the whole text.

Comment: it is not a specific line it is a part of a page, either the main page body or the page head and foot that does not fit in its specified space. the log will show which page and if you add `\showoutput` then the `[]` you show will be expanded to show the contents of the overfill box.

Comment: A minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem, could help us to help you.

Comment: This is just a warning. Besides, `1.83182pt` converts to `0.025347` inches or `0.064381` centimeters, which is probably why you can’t *see* where the problem is.